# Why hidden input field values can't be empty

Tags: php, multipartform-data

I'm using PHP form to send user registration data and then handle it with PHP form. I need to register a few user types such as "normal users," "admin users," "edit enabled users," etc. Details requests for registration of every kind of user are different. But I hope to use the same formDataManagement.php file. When I click the "Submit" button, an error message shows.

> Undefined array Key.

**Form data section**

```
<input type="hidden" id="companyname" name="companyname" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="regno" name="regno" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="farmaddress" name="farmaddress" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="role" name="role" value="admin">
<input type="hidden" id="designation" name="designation" value="manager">
```

**formDataManagement.php**

```
//if user signup button
if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $conpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['conpassword']);
    $compName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['companyname']);
    $role = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['role']);
    $regno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['regno']);
    $designation = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['designation']);
    $farm_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['farmaddress']);
    $resi_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['resaddress']);
}
```

But after the process, it shows the following error.

> Warning: Undefined array key "companyname" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\admin\register\formDataManagement.php on line 15
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "regno" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\admin\register\formDataManagement.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "farmaddress" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\admin\register\formDataManagement.php on line 22

Can't I send empty values as hidden input values?
Please advise solving this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `hidden` without `type="hidden"` like `<input hidden id="companyname" name="companyname" value=""/>`. You can set for type `type="text"`.
2. Also try to close elements: `<input hidden type="text" id="companyname" name="companyname" value=""/>` or `</input>`.

So here is perfect input element:`<input hidden type="text" id="companyname" name="companyname" value=""/>`

Comment: Thanks Lot , i spent more than 2 days to solve this by referring various books and sites. it work fine. Thank Lot.

Comment: @Manojs No problem, You are very welcome! I'm glad my answer solved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

I can't determine the exact problem with only your currently given code, but the problem might be caused by any of the followings:

- You didn't use [POST method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) to send the data in the form.
- You put the three input fields outside of the form.
- Your submit button doesn't work properly, especially when you have a pre-submit JS function before submitting the form.
- And more (please include more of your codes)

**You definitely *can* send empty values as hidden input values. Although the content will be empty, it will never give out warnings.**

From MDN (description of `input="hidden"`):

> A control that is not displayed but whose value is submitted to the
> server.